# TDD in Cart application

Tags: tdd

So I have an academic problem of simulating a Cart service.

A Cart supports addition of an OrderItem and another responsibility of calculating the total price of the particular cart. This is done via composition and delegation to IPricingCalculator as

```
public class Cart
{
private List<OrderItem> _items;
private IPricingCalculator _pricingCalculator;

public Cart(IPricingCalculator pricingCalculator);
public addItem(OrderItem);

public double totalPrice()
{
double price = 0.0;
for (OrderItem orderItem: _items)
    price += _pricingCalculator.getPrice(orderItem);
}

}
```

IPricingCalculator supports the getPrice method as

```
public interface IPricingCalculator
{
double getPrice(OrderItem item);
}
```

CustomPriceCalculator implements the IPricingCalculator interface

```
public class CustomCalculator implements IPricingCalculator
{
private List<IPriceRule> _priceRules;
public double getPrice(OrderItem item); // return the price according to the first rule that matches
}
```

Now I have implemented CustomCalculator in TDD way,
these are some of my tests:

```
@Test
public void FreeItemCostNothing();
public void SpecialItemCostHalf();
public void BulkPurchaseCostsQuater();
```

and so on.

And I am pretty sure that CustomCalculator is working fine.

But I do not understand what according to TDD should be my next step for implementing Cart, all Cart is supposed to do is manage a collection of OrderItem and fold the getPrice method on the collection. Should I have same exhaustive test suite for both the classes?

I.e should the test of the Cart include following such tests too-

```
@Test
public void TenFreeItemCostNothing();
public void FiveSpecialItemsAndBulkPurchaseCostsHalfAndQuarter();
```

etc etc

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are most of the way to your answer.

You should write tests to test the two things that `Cart` needs to support.

```
@Test
public void AddOrderItemToCart(); /* I don't see these in the interface, but... */
public void DeleteOrderItemFromCart();
public void GetPriceMethodIsCorrectlyCalled();
public void AllOrderItemsArePricedAndTotalCalculated();
```

These tests could either verify the calls by verifying mocks (not sure if this works in the language you are using (Java or C#)) or by calling actual instances and making sure the results are ok. You shouldn't test the implementation of OrderItem or your `CustomCalculator` again, just that it is correctly called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Lukas...

I have written tests for AddOrderToCart, I am not supporting Deletion. My problem is how to test AllOrderItemsArePricesAndTotalCalculated...

I have a lot of items, each of which can be discounted in different ways. I wrote such tests in the CustomCalculatorTests like I mentioned. Should I redo all theses test cases in Cart again?

Comment: And thanks I added the method of adding to the cart, and have also added the tests that I am doubtful are required or not... Please have a look and let me know, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your description you have implemented your `CustomPriceCalculator` in a test-driven way, meaning you followed those steps:

1. Write a failing unit test
2. Make the failing test pass
3. Refactor

You are facing an interesting problem which is usually caused by not following the full TDD test cycle. Which would be:

1. Write a failing acceptance test
2. Write a failing unit test
3. Make the failing test pass
4. Refactor
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until the failing acceptance test passes

The acceptance test is an end-to-end test which should cut through your whole application stack (e.g. from the UI over buisness logic to database and back). This is necessary to give structure to your code. It let you define the missing pieces in your code and the collaborators you need to implement. It also creates a guide that let you focus your programming to the necessary parts of your application.

If you intend to learn TDD you probably want to spend some time studying [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627). It will provide you with all you need to get TDD going properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jesko,

I have watched Foundation of Programming- TDD lessons from Lynda.com and they didn't seem to mention this cycle of TDD. It was only Red-Green-Grey cycle which basically said that in TDD we are supposed to do Unit Tests, and that Unit Tests are not other tests (acceptance, integration etc)

So I am a little confused here, are you suggesting that there are no unit tests for the Cart class and it can only be tested with an acceptance test?

My question was rather how to test my Cart class, specifically totalPrice method

Comment: No, not at all. Each component has to be unit tested (if possible), but acceptance tests give you a starting and end point for the feature you want to implement. Once you start using acceptance tests you get a web of interconnected nodes instead of loosely hanging components.

Comment: Okk.. Right now I don't think I am at a point where I can write acceptance tests, or rather my academic problem is currently simple enough to live without it. But this still doesn't answer my original question, can you please check it again.. I have done some refinements to the question. And thanks a lot for the input Jesko :)